# Can any one Guide me which Audio Player I should use for my aplication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, html5-audio, audio-player

I am creating an application on Ruby on Rails in which I want to embed an Audio-player to play song in play list. Can anyone guide me with which audio player I should go with ?

Comment: The best audio player in the world is [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org) and this question should be closed because it will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: come on , he asks for an audioplayer he can use from rals, not for the best audioplauer around, i know of ways to play audio from Ruby, but froms rails you would best look for a javascript solution since that is the way you would play the audio in the client browser code

Comment: @peter, my point was to give a useful answer and at the same time sarcastically point out that this will likely solicit debate, because other people will have other opinions about the best audio player in the world. By the way, jPlayer *IS* a javascript solution.

Comment: ok, then we are fine but there are allready 4 votes to close this question and i'm afraid some because your remark. Why not make an answer of it, accompanied by a small example ?

Comment: @peter, I didn't make the rules but someone decided that these kind of  questions are not welcome (for good reasons IMO). Answering may encourage someone to ask more inappropriate questions. He can click on the link in my original comment and find plenty of examples.